# R Problems with POSIXlt and mutate within a function

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, posixlt

I´m working on project with n data frames. Before i can work with them some processing is nescessary.
One of these operations is to add a column for "year", "month" and "day" to each data frame. The also got and keep a column "date" in the format "yyyy - mm - dd".

```
dateiNamen<-dir(path="input_folder",pattern = "merged", all.files = T)

Auswertung<-function(Dateiname){
  setwd("input_folder")
  data<-read.delim(Dateiname, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  data$date<-as.Date(data$date)
  data<-subset(data, data$date>"1994-12-31")
  data<-data[,colMeans(is.na(data))<0.15]
  
  Ausgabedatei <- paste0("output_folder",Dateiname, "_bearbeitet",".csv")
  write.table(data, file = Ausgabedatei, row.names = F, col.names = T, sep=",")
  setwd("Project_folder")
}

fun<-lapply(dateiNamen, Auswertung)
```

That´s the first step and it works as it should, after this the "date" column (XX$date) of any of these data frames got the following structure:

```
head(XX$date)
[1] "1995-01-01" "1995-01-02" "1995-01-03" "1995-01-04" "1995-01-05" "1995-01-06"

str(XX$date)
 Date[1:9131], format: "1995-01-01" "1995-01-02" "1995-01-03" "1995-01-04" "1995-01-05" "1995-01-06" "1995-01-07" "1995-01-08" "1995-01-09" "1995-01-10" ...

class(XX$date)
[1] "Date"

dput(head(XX$date))
structure(c(9131, 9132, 9133, 9134, 9135, 9136), class = "Date")
```

Now, i apply my second function on the data frames to create the colums for year, month and day in each data frame:

```
dateiNamen2<-dir(path="output_folder",pattern = "merged", all.files = T)

Spalten<-function(Dateiname){
  setwd("output_folder")
  data<-read.csv(Dateiname,header = TRUE, ";")
  
  
  data<-data%>%
        dplyr::mutate(     year = lubridate::year(date), 
                                 month = lubridate::month(date),
                                 day = lubridate::day(date))
  
  Ausgabedatei <- paste0("output_folder_2",Dateiname, "_bearbeitet",".csv")
  write.table(data, file = Ausgabedatei, row.names = F, col.names = T, sep = ",")
  setwd("Project_folder")
}

fun2<-lapply(dateiNamen2, Spalten)
```

When i apply this function i get the following error:

```
**Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz=tz(x)): 
dont know how to convert "x" in class ""POSIXlt""**
```

**I cant figure it out what is causing this problem, cause if i´m running the same commands on a single file it works perfectly.
Maybe one of you sees something i missed.**

And yeah the functions could be "prettier", but they are the first functions i ever wrote. i´ll keep trying! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this function :

```
Spalten<-function(Dateiname){

  data <- read.csv2(Dateiname) #.....(1)
  data <- data %>%
            dplyr::mutate(date = as.Date(date),            #.....(2)
                          year = lubridate::year(date), 
                          month = lubridate::month(date),
                          day = lubridate::day(date))
  
  Ausgabedatei <- paste0("output_folder_2/",Dateiname, "_bearbeitet",".csv") #.....(3)
  write.table(data, file = Ausgabedatei, row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE, sep = ",")
}

dateiNamen2 <- list.files(path="output_folder",pattern = "merged", 
                          all.files = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) #.....(4)
fun2 <- lapply(dateiNamen2, Spalten)
```

1. Used `read.csv2` since it has default `sep = ";"` and `header` is always `TRUE` for `read.csv` functions.
2. I don't think the date would automatically read into "Date" class if we don't explicitly mention the class in `read.csv2` so better we convert it to "Date" class first.
3. If `"output_folder_2"` is the name of the folder it should have a `"/"` to separate filename and folder name.
4. Using `list.files` instead of `dir` to create file names with `full.names = TRUE` so that it returns the full path of the file and we don't have to use `setwd`.
5. Wouldn't it be better to combine the things which you are doing in `Auswertung` and `Spalten` functions in one function and read and write the files once instead of doing it separately in each function.

Comment: 1. Okay, changed that. Thanks!

2.. I tried your version, but i´m now getting the following error

"Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "Date"

Could it be that "mutate" cant work with "Date" and this should be class "date" instead, but how?

3. The slash is there, i just forget to write it in the example.

4. Thanks!

5. Of course, it would bu much better, but these are my first functions i write and i´m happy if they are working. 
but yeah, combining them would decrease the possiblity of bugs.

Comment: `Dateiname` is the path of the filename, right? and you are reading the csv in `data` with more than 1 columns? It should work actually. Try to run it for one file outside the function. What does `data <- read.csv2(dateiNamen2[1])` return in `data` ?